# Any way to make dispatch_queue_t work in single thread?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperationqueue, nsthread

Here is my code:

```
@interface MyObject ()
@property(nonatomic) dispatch_queue_t queue;
@end

@implementation MyObject {
    NSThread *_check;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.Thread.queue", NULL);
        dispatch_async(_queue, ^{
            _check = [NSThread currentThread]; //for ex. thread number = 3
            //some code here...
        });
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)someMethod:(MyObjClass *)obj {
    dispatch_async(_queue, ^{
        //need th
        if (_check != [NSThread currentThread]) { // it is sometimes number 3, but sometimes it changes
            NSLog(@"Thread changed.");
        }
        [obj doSmth]; //got crash if currentThread != _check         
    });
}

@end
```

I need to make sure that all MyObjClass's methods performs in the same thread. But this code change thread by it's own will, but sometimes it work in single thread. Any way I can force it to use same thread all the time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a word, no. Other than the main queue, GCD does not have any notion of thread affinity.  If you really need thread affinity, GCD is not really the right tool. If you like the idiom, and want to kind of "adapt" something to your needs you could do something like this:

```
@implementation AppDelegate
{
    NSThread* thread;
}

void dispatch_thread_async(NSThread* thread, dispatch_block_t block)
{
    if ([NSThread currentThread] == thread)
    {
        block();
    }
    else
    {
        block = [block copy];
        [(id)block performSelector: @selector(invoke) onThread: thread withObject: nil waitUntilDone: NO];
    }
}

void dispatch_thread_sync(NSThread* thread, dispatch_block_t block)
{
    if ([NSThread currentThread] == thread)
    {
        block();
    }
    else
    {
        [(id)block performSelector: @selector(invoke) onThread: thread withObject: nil waitUntilDone: YES];
    }
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget: self selector:@selector(threadMain) object:nil];
    [thread start];

    dispatch_thread_async(thread, ^{
        NSLog(@"Async Thread: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
    });

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        dispatch_thread_sync(thread, ^{
            NSLog(@"Sync Thread: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
        });
    });
}

- (void)threadMain
{
    // You need the NSPort here because a runloop with no sources or ports registered with it
    // will simply exit immediately instead of running forever.
    NSPort* keepAlive = [NSPort port];
    NSRunLoop* rl = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [keepAlive scheduleInRunLoop: rl forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    [rl run];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thx, that is exactly what I was looking for. Also one thing to mention - it works ~10% slower then sample with GCD only.

Comment: Yeah, GCD is pretty highly optimized. I'm surprised the penalty is *only* 10%.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have multiple instances of your class,  you are overwriting your queue with each new init.

A singleton or a static could be used to resolve the issue.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. But it is not the problem,it is ok to have different thread for each instance. In my case I set **_check** after init and I got problem only if `_check != [NSThread currentThread]`.

Answer (score 0):

You would either create one serial queue and dispatch to that serial queue, or you would dispatch all your work items to the main queue. A serial queue has the advantage that all the workitems in the queue will be handled one after the other, so you don't have to worry about synchronising between them, but they will also all run in one thread per serial queue.

You should not ever inquire what thread you are running on. If you dispatched your work item to the main queue, then you are running on the main thread. If you dispatched your work item to a serial queue, then you are running on the thread for that queue. If you dispatched your work item to a concurrent queue, then there is no guarantee whatsoever which thread you are running on, and you shouldn't care.

Comment: "but they will also all run in one thread per serial queue."

@gnasher729, When I worked on this problem a few years ago - serial dispatch queue did not guarantee that the execution items would be called on the same thread.
Pretty sure that this behavior hasn't changed. So your answer is not suitable to solve this problem. 

A little more context - the problem was related Realm database and the restriction of using objects on a single thread.
i.e. you will get a crash when accessing object from any other thread.